# wpf bind to image, not displaying

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I'm using a WPF ListView to display a bunch of content. I have a number of columns defined where the displayed value in each cell is a property in the underlying object. What I'm trying to do is show an image in certain columns in the event that certain properties are true and I'm running into issues binding. The look I'm going for is if the user is an admin we show a star or something like that.

I tried the following.

```
    <ListView Name="MyListview" Grid.Row="3">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>                    
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Pix}" Header="Pix"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Code Behind

```
    private static BitmapImage s_brandImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\pix.png", UriKind.Relative));

    public BitmapImage Pix
    {
        get
        {
            return s_brandImage;

            //Image i = new Image();
            //i.Source = s_brandImage;
            //return i;
        }
    }
```

What I get when I run the app is in the ListView it just prints the URI that I put in the BitmapImage object and I don't get a picture.

I'm flying by the seat of my pants so any suggestions are appreciated.
mj

Comment: change the celltemplate of the gridviewcolumn to show image and bind the image source to that Pix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the GridView hosted inside ListView as follows.

```
 <GridView>
     <GridViewColumn Header="Pix">
         <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <Image Source="{Binding Pix}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>                   
 </GridView>
```

Also change the Uri kind of the Uri object as given below.

```
private static BitmapImage s_brandImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\pix.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: Or don't specify the UriKind at all: `new Uri(@"C:\pix.png")`